# Can I add reCaptcha to a form built using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, recaptcha

I need to add recaptcha to a forum new post form which is generated in an XSL file via an XSLTprocessor file. Can anyone advise of a tutorial or recaptcha documentation that will apply for this process of whether it is even possible at all?

It doesn't have to use recaptcha, if it is easier to use another captcha method than I will gladly implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "recaptcha"? How this relates to XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to generate ANY (X)Html with XSLT. It's generally easier to generate XHTML, simply because it's XML compliant, and you can include XHTML fragments within your stylesheet. Although XSLT 1.0 doesn't have 'xhtml' as a valid output method, you can just use 'xml' (which is the default anyway), and include the XHTML namespace.

The most basic example (and often a good starting point) is this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <!-- xhtml code here -->
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This just generates the contents of that template, and doesn't take anything from the XML input. From there, you can replace actual xhtml code with xsl instructions that pull data from your input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do I add your suggestion above directly within the XSL file that contains the form, or do I create a new XSL file as a template and then call in this new template into the XSL file that contains the form? How would I allow <?php ?> to be used within the above (if I use php tags instead of the html tags, it just doesn't seem to process the php so it is outputted on the front end).

Comment: Well, typically I'd expect the XSLT to be done by the client; given that php's done in the server, any php generated by the XSLT isn't going to be processed. If you're using PHP, then your PHP code needs to generate the source XML server side, and dish it up to the browser with a stylesheet instruction attached.